# Using \= in vim regex search

Tags: regex, vim

I've come across the metacharacter `\=` in vim, which I've never seen before. It seems in line with:

- `\*` (0 or more, greedy)
- `\+` (1 or more, greedy)
- `\=` (0 or 1, greedy?)

If that is the case, is this a shorthand/alias for `{0,1}`, or is this used for something else?

Comment: Yes, it is a quantifier for regex patterns (e.g. `:help \=`, which states:  \= Matches 0 or 1 of the preceding atom, as many as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `\*` in your question matches just literal `*`.

`\=` and `\?`, it does also what`\{0,1}` does.

The only difference between `\=` and `\?` is, when you do a backward search with `?`, you cannot use the `\?`, this is because the `?` interfered the `? (search)` command.